# Need to create dynamic hyperlink or change cell remotely

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I've created a google spreadsheet. It has a master sheet, and I made a query function to pull data for my team.
My team has to update the column that has a comment section. But pulled data cannot be changed.

Now I need either of solutions:
1. Change the original cell in the master sheet remotely
2. Have a dynamic hyperlink to the cell they need to update

Here what I would want for the option №2 in my google spreadsheet - [excel example I found on the internet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9rJh.gif)

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

> I believe this is what you were looking for (if not please clarify a bit more your question): you want to create a dropdown list that depending on the name on it the link next to it will change accordingly to direct you to the specific cell of that person in the other sheet.

If that is the case here is the simplified piece of code that will achieve this with self explanatory comments:

```js
function onEdit() {
  // Get the two sheets
  var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  
  // Create an array for the dropdown list
  var names = ['Ramon', 'Jose', 'Pepito'];
  
  // Build the dropdown data validation
  var dropdown = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(names).build();
  // Set the dropdown to your desired ccell and attach the validation to that cell
  var dropdownCell = ss1.getRange('A1');
  dropdownCell.setDataValidation(dropdown);
  
  // For every case of your dropdown (for every name) create an if condition so that the link on the side keeps changing
  // accordingly to who is set on the drop down (i.e repeat this step for the rest of the names).
  if(dropdownCell.getValue()=='Ramon'){
    // Set the vale of B1 to the hyperlink formula (you need to get your linked sheet id and the range or cell you want to link it to.
    ss1.getRange("B1").setValue('=hyperlink("#gid='+ss2.getSheetId()+'&range='+ss1.getRange('B112').getA1Notation()+'", "Click to jump to Sheet 2")');
  }
}
```

For achieving this I took use of the [formula hyperlink](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093313?hl=en) and of the Apps Script tool for [creating data validation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#newdatavalidation) and [setting it to a specific cell](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder). Moreover, the use of `onEdit()` will allow you to [catch instant changes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) in the dropdown cell.

I hope this has helped you. Let me know if you need anything else or if you did not understood something. :)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help.
My case has a twist, instead of a dropdown list I have cells with comments. They have to be changed, so every time they are different. 
Here is a simplified example. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FgxhVrGj_VG6T4MCWxTEwl1q3tBVIUFr/view?usp=sharing

So John in his sheet can't edit comments. He have to go to the sheet that can be edited "Sheet with data". 
As comments in John's sheet are exactly the same, I wonder if it possible to jump to that specific cell in the master sheet "Sheet with data"?